# Organic Group: Can not create group type content?

Tags: organic-groups

I have *Organic Groups* installed on my website. I have a content type with OG setting as **Group**. I had several contents of this type. And then all of a sudden, I started getting the following error when I try to create a content of this type:

`Can't save entity as group, because user admin can't be subscribed to group and become a manager.`

What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the number of value for the group_group field to unlimited.
That field must be in the content type which you defined as group.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, it was caused by a recently deleted group still in the og_membership table. I had og field access enabled, and it was trying to determine if I had rights to write to the fields within the group. It didn't recognize the new node being created, so og searched through other groups my user was a member of to learn of my field rights. It saw a group in og_membership that technically didn't exist, and returned FALSE instead of null.

Anyway, this patch may help you: https://drupal.org/node/1538658#comment-8182821

Try it out! Disclosure: it's my patch :) If it works for you, make a comment in the drupal issue queue saying so.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
Go to Configuration > People > Account Setting > Manage Fields > Edit Group membership Field > Scroll down to GROUP *MEMBERSHIP FIELD SETTINGS* and Make Number of value **Unlimited** > Save and Enjoy